# "Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence" with Springer LNCS bst (splncs04)

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, input-encodings, lncs

My co-authors are using Overleaf to prepare a manuscript using the [Springer LNCS style](https://www.springer.com/it/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines) (version 2.21). The bibliography entries contain names with various non-ASCII letters, such as the dotted G (Ġ), *some* (but not all) of which cause "Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence" errors when compiling with `pdflatex`. (Similar errors are triggered when compiling with `xelatex` and `lualatex`.)  The problem seems to occur only when using Springer's `bst` file, but not when using BibTeX's default bibliography styles.

The problem is also reproducible when compiling the document offline with TeX Live 2022, which uses `utf8` as its default input encoding.  I've verified that the input files are definitely UTF-8–encoded and the offending characters are valid UTF-8 sequences. Using `bibtexu` instead of `bibtex` works around the problem, but there doesn't seem to be any way of telling Overleaf to use `bibtexu`.

What's the cause of the problem and what's the best way of fixing or working around it so that we can continue to use Overleaf?  Unfortunately, we are obliged to use the Springer bibliography style, but perhaps there is some way we can patch it?

I suppose one workaround would be to rewrite the offending letters in the `bib` file with LaTeX command sequences (e.g., `${\mathrm{\dot{G}}}$` for Ġ), though this ends up mixing text and math fonts and prevents us from simply copying and pasting existing bibliography entries into the file. Besides, our bibliography file may contain dozens of different non-ASCII characters and it's not clear to us which need to be replaced. (The problem occurs with some letters but not others.)

Here is a minimal example demonstrating the problem:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @incollection{foo,
  title = {Foo},
  booktitle = {Bar},
  author = {Mathurin, Élise and Mallia, Ġorġ},
  year = {2022},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{foo}
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am quite sure that this accent can be written using tex code without math mode. Not at pc will check later

Comment: Found it: `{\.{G}}or{\.{g}}` ought to do the trick

Comment: @daleif Great; that takes care of the specific case of Ġ. But it would still be nice to have a generic solution that allows UTF-8 characters to be used as-is on Overleaf.

Comment: Hi, Tom from Overleaf Support here. There is probably a way how to use `bibtexu`, but I need to test this first to be sure... I'll be right back :)

Comment: @yo' bibtexu has been removed from texlive (for good reasons) so I advice you not to start to support it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm running TeX Live 2022 and bibtexu is still present. Do you rather mean that it's _going_ to be removed?

Comment: I don't have it anymore. Are you sure you are using a bibtexu from texlive 2022 and not from some other place?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yeah, I just realize that. Well, there is a solution how to get any binary running in place of bibtex, I'll make a quick answer.

Comment: you can't use utf8 character at the begin of names, as bibtex tries to create initials here. But you can protect them by hiding them inside a command argument, e.g. `{\relax{É}}lise`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, it's at /opt/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/bibtexu. I installed TeX Live 2022 (from the official ISO) only a few weeks ago and told it to use /opt/texlive as the installation path.  Is it possible the installer copied that binary from an earlier installation of TeX Live?

Comment: no idea. On windows it isn't there and Karl wrote me some time ago that he will remove it, so I assumed that it is gone on linux too. I any case I can't recommend it, I ran a number of tests and had lots of failures.

Comment: https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/bin/x86_64-linux/ and https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/bin/win32/ suggest that `bibtexu` is included for Linux (x86 64 bit) but not Windows...

Answer (score 1):

*(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)*

There is a way to run `bibtexu` in place of `bibtex` in Overleaf, however, as noted by Ulrike Fischer, the tool is not in general well supported and shall be removed from TeX Live.

In order to run is, you can create a file called `latexmkrc` (without any file extension) in the top folder of your project, and add the following line to it:

```
$bibtex = `bibtexu %O %S`
```

However, I wasn't able to get `bibtexu` to work properly, so I'll leave that part to you, maybe you'll be luckier.